# TypeError: Cannot read property 'events' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I've been trying to create a todo like app but here instead of todo, I'm adding an event where I can create, delete and view the events without the update part. I've set up my actions, reducers, store files. To set up a fake api, I've used json-server. The format for the backend data is something like `{posts:[id, title, place]}`. However, when I run my file then I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'events' of undefined`. I need help to run the app. I've also set up a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-pare-kf7p7?file=/src/actions/types.js) to see the whole project

Events.js

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import EventItem from './EventItem';
import EventForm from './EventForm';
import { getEvents } from '../../actions/events';

const Events = ({ getEvents, event: { events } }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getEvents();
  }, [getEvents]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h1 className="large text-primary">Posts</h1>
      <p className="lead">
        <i className="fas fa-user" /> Your Events
      </p>
      <EventForm />
      <div className="posts">
        {events.map((event) => (
          <EventItem key={event.id} event={event} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

Events.propTypes = {
  getEvents: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  event: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  event: state.event
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getEvents })(Events);
```

action.js

```
import {CREATE_EVENT, GET_EVENTS, DELETE_EVENT } from "./types";
import api from '../utils/api';
export const getEvents = () => async dispatch => {
    try {
      const res = await api.get('/posts');
  
      dispatch({
        type: GET_EVENTS,
        payload: res.data
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  };

  export const deleteEvent =(id)=>async dispatch=>{
      try{
          await api.delete(`/posts/${id}`)
          dispatch({
              type: DELETE_EVENT,
              payload: id
          })
      }catch(err){
          console.log(err)
      }
  }


  // Add post
export const createEvent = formData => async dispatch => {
    try {
      const res = await api.post('/posts', formData);
  
      dispatch({
        type: CREATE_EVENT,
        payload: res.data
      });
  
      
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  };
```

reducer.js

```
import {CREATE_EVENT, GET_EVENTS, DELETE_EVENT} from "../actions/types";

const initialState={
    events: [],
    }

export default function(state=initialState, action){
    const {type, payload} = action;
    switch(type){
        case GET_EVENTS: 
            return {
                ...state,
                events: payload,
     
        
            };
        case CREATE_EVENT:
            return {
                ...state,
                events: [payload, ...state.events],
            };
        case DELETE_EVENT:
            return {
                ...state,
                events: state.events.filter(event=>event.id !==payload),
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out, i have fixed your issue : codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-microservice-fcntj

use `state.events` instead of `state.event` because you have register it as events in reducer not event

```
 const mapStateToProps = state => ({
      event: state.events 
    });
```

Comment: wow that worked. can you also help me why the delete thing is not working?

Comment: yeah share your code, where are you dispatching `deleteAction` ?

Comment: in the `eventItem.js` file, I've dispatched the delete button. I've given the `id` there so that it can delete the item corresponding with that id. the red color button in the component is the delete button

Comment: check this now: https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-microservice-fcntj?file=/src/components/events/EventItem.js

Comment: actually you only need to pass `deleteEvent` function directly, it is not triggering on callback

Comment: it's not deleting the items in your updated sandbox

Comment: no error. just that the item is not being deleted. the item is still being shown in the component

Comment: in `eventItem` file, the prop deletePost is there instead  of deleteEvent, could that be the reason? I mistaknely wrote deletePost there

Comment: yeah probably that was the error `deletePost` check now: https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-microservice-fcntj?file=/src/components/events/EventItem.js

Comment: nice. it works now. thanks. I can't delete or post an item to db.json file, right? or is that possible?

Comment: yeah, you should not delete from file, you should delete from your state :)

Comment: it may sound really dumb but can you show it how to delete and post the items to the db.json file too?

Comment: then you need to configure javascript file system, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40537990/removing-json-object-from-json-file

Comment: just one last question, how to make json-server work in codesandbox